# How to delay shutdown/restart/hibernate in windows 7 or windows 8 in VC++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012

I am using vs2012 based application developed using C++.

If application is running and doing some processing and user triggers restart/shutdown or hibernate, then restart/shutdown should be suspended until application processing is done.

Once application processing is done, windows should resume to restart/shutdown.

I would highly appreciate if some references or example code to the same can be available

Thanks

Comment: I would not close the question, it is quite specific, targeting some obscure windows API protocol (might be a gray zone)

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this

```
bool shutdownSystemWin(EShutdownActions action)
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;

    // Get a token for this process.
    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),
        TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
        return false;

    // Get the LUID for the shutdown privilege.
    LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME,
        &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid);

    tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;  // one privilege to set
    tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    // Get the shutdown privilege for this process.
    AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0,
        (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0);

    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return false;

    // Shut down the system and force all applications to close.
    UINT flags = EWX_FORCE;
    switch (action)
    {
    case EShutdownActions::Shutdown:
        flags |= EWX_SHUTDOWN;
        break;
    case EShutdownActions::PowerOff:
        flags |= EWX_POWEROFF;
        break;
    case EShutdownActions::SuspendToRAM:
        return SetSuspendState(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);
    case EShutdownActions::Hibernate:
        return SetSuspendState(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE);
        break;
    case EShutdownActions::Reboot:
        flags |= EWX_REBOOT;
        break;
    case EShutdownActions::LogOff:
        flags |= EWX_LOGOFF;
        break;
    }

    if (!ExitWindowsEx(flags,
        SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_OPERATINGSYSTEM |
        SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_UPGRADE |
        SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED))
        return false;

    //shutdown was successful
    return true;
}
```